Google Sheets timelines feature - reduce number of rows
I am using the Timeline feature from Google Sheets.
Everything is working as intended, but I would like to consolidate or reduce the number of rows that are on the timeline, so it is more like a calendar view. IE if I have 4 things on April 4-10, there should be separate lines for them, but when the next thing that starts on April 12-16 should be on the same row as the first entry. Reducing the stack so to speak.
Here is a link to a sample sheet.
Basically, I would like Test 4 to start back in at the top since it no longer overlaps. The data will be sorted by date already.
If there is an alternative way to do this in Google Sheets (a proper calendar view fed by a spreadsheet), I am not opposed to exploring the option, but we'd prefer that it stays in Sheets if at all possible.

Timeline features in Google Sheets are kind of limited in terms of the requested changes on your current project. What you can do instead is explore the options of smart chips to replicate current issues. Though your post doesn't include more comprehensive information about your requirements and goals. So for starters I want to recommend apps scirpt for Google sheets and card builders. Maybe this more suited with your project.
